# Linux Redhat 5.5

Tags: linux

5

but yum is not working when i use

[root@localhost ~]# rpm -q yum
yum-3.2.22-26.el5

when i run

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
This system is not registered with RHN.
RHN support will be disabled.
Skipping security plugin, no data
Setting up Update Process
No Packages marked for Update
```

when i tried to install another version of yum it gives

```
[root@localhost ~]# rpm -ivh yum-3.2.29-30.el6.noarch.rpm 
warning: yum-3.2.29-30.el6.noarch.rpm: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 192a7d7d
error: Failed dependencies:
        pygpgme is needed by yum-3.2.29-30.el6.noarch
        python(abi) = 2.6 is needed by yum-3.2.29-30.el6.noarch
        python-urlgrabber >= 3.9.0-8 is needed by yum-3.2.29-30.el6.noarch
        rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by yum-3.2.29-30.el6.noarch
        rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by yum-3.2.29-30.el6.noarch
        yum-basearchonly conflicts with yum-3.2.22-26.el5.noarch
        yum-skip-broken conflicts with yum-3.2.22-26.el5.noarch
```

please help me in this how can i use yum

Comment: Do you have a valid license from RedHat? That sounds like you might not have access to RHN (RedHat Network) because you're not paying RedHat.

Comment: Besides not being registered with RHN, you're trying to manually install an RPM from RHEL 6 onto an RHEL 5 system.  That's what the 'el6' in the rpm filename means.

Answer (score 5):

It clearly states that your systen isn't registered with RedHat, which is required to get security updates. Either buy/register a support license or switch to something else (like CentOS).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like u haven't configured any repositories to use `yum` with and as @SvenW said - no rhn support here. 
Check directory `/etc/yum.repos.d` for configs.